# What is USB port on oscilloscope is for ? Can I power my Arduino from it?

Tags: arduino, usb, oscilloscope

I have a DS1102e oscilloscope (by Rigol,) picture attached below.

I'm new to oscilloscopes and watched plenty of tutorials on how to use them, but I couldn't find the answer to my question.

I need to power my Arduino Uno, I can certainly do it from a PC but my workbench and pc are far apart.

**Q)** Can I power my board from the USB port on my oscilloscope?

**Q)** Will it damage my board?

**Q)** What is the general use of a USB port on an oscilloscope?

[image]

Please bear with me if my questions sounds stupid, I'm new to this stuff.

Comment: There are different use-case, moslty to upgrade firmware, but on some models you can use an USB mouse for mesure functions  & the interesting point on your question, is that in most cases, it just feet the USB norm so YES you can then power a device from it until you do not use more than 5v 500mA of course.

Comment: The normal use is a USB flash drive to store screen captures.

Comment: I would be much more concerned about the board damaging the scope, than the scope damaging the board. After all, that scope is worth 20-30 Aurduino Unos.

Comment: @AndrejaKo Haha, actually i own the scope and have borrowed the board from my friend, I dont want to return it damaged...Im just using arduino to generate PWM signals for my delay circuit. would you suggest runing the UNO from oscilloscope usb port?

Comment: [You have a DS1102e.  This is the user's guide for it.](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/Users%2BGuide%2BDS1000E.pdf) **Read** it.  It will answer all your questions about what the USB port is for on your oscilloscope.  The manufacturer knows more about your device than random videos on youtube do.

Comment: It's healthy to be concerned for the scope... but the ironic thing is that basic ones like this cost less than most computers (unless your lab machine was retired from some other usage).  That said the USB design may not be as robust because they don't really expect to see anything but a flash drive.   But you're probably going to want to program or get serial data from that board soon, and the scope is unlikely to do that.

Answer (score 3):

If that Arduino is the device you're trying to debug, and there's external circuitry connected to it, I strongly suggest NOT to power it from the scope. One silly mistake (a short in just the wrong place, back-EMF spike from a motor, wrong external voltage, etc.) and you risk to blow up not only a $20 Arduino, but also a $250 scope.

Just get a $5 USB power supply.

Answer (score 2):

The main intent for a USB device port like this on a scope is for transferring data from the scope. This could be images or data files.

Often, you can also use a mouse and/or keyboard with that port.

Depending on the design, you should be able to power a USB device. The odds are very good that Rigol used an off-the-shelf USB design to implement this port, so it should be able to handle standard USB power needs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was going to suggest it is so you can play your favorite music, but I think it is to save data files (as CSV or other formats) to and a quick search found this so that should help. You need to check for your specific model...

[Quick way to get data off the Rigol scope](https://physicscourses.colorado.edu/phys4430/phys4430_fa18/CheatSheets/Interfacing%20Rigol%20DS1052%20scopes%20with%20a%20computer.pdf)

Having briefly read the above pdf, it is also possible to have software on a computer that then communicates with the oscilloscope - not sure what functionality you get though...

And from @JRE here is the [link](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/Users%2BGuide%2BDS1000E.pdf) to the pdf for your model.

Comment: PC communication uses the USB *device mode* type B connector on the back, not the pictured type A connector on the front.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar port on other devices used for transferring data for firmware and software updates or it could possibly be used to interface a diagnostic tool in case the scope goes kaput.